# Synonyme de insensible dans le milieu scientifique

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, science

J'ai un mot sur le bout de la langue, mais je n'arrive pas à le trouver.

Il s'agit d'un mot qui décrirait un ensemble de données lorsque celui-ci n'a pas été affecté par un événement.

Ainsi, on pourrait dire :

> En comparant les courbes de température des stations météo de la région, on voit que toutes montrent que les températures ont augmenté durant la canicule sauf celles venant du Col du Bouquetin. Ces dernières sont {insensibles ou un synonyme plus scientifique} à la canicule, ce qui peut être expliqué par le froid de la montagne.

Comment: Si les températures ont augmenté dans les stations météo de la région, ce que les les courbes sont "**sensibles**" à la canicule, pas le contraire.

Comment: Je pense qu'il parle de la courbe du *Col du Bouquetin* qui semblerait coller avec la 2ème partie de la dernière phrase (montagne). Je pense que *Cette courbe est indépendante de la canicule, ce qui s'expliquer par le froid en montagne.* me semble correct.

Comment: @stbr Oui, j'ai remanié la phrase pour que ce soit clair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ces courbes *ne* sont *pas affectées / impactées par* la canicule, restent *inchangées / stables malgré* la canicule.

Ce ne sont pas les tournures qui manquent...

Comment: Attention à `impacter`, qui a [mauvaise presse](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/impacter).

Comment: Disons que l'Académie (dont l'autorité est largement sans conséquence sur l'usage du français) réprouve. Mais bon, l'usage, lui, est bien réel : https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/impacter

Answer (score 5):

Je propose:

> Ces courbes sont *indépendantes* de la canicule.

Answer (score 4):

On pourrait dire :

> Ces courbes *ne* sont *pas liées* (ou *corrélées*) à la canicule,

Comment: Sympa les votes négatifs, une explication serait la bienvenue !

Comment: @Fólkvangr: La [canicule](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canicule) n'est pas une variation de température mais l'installation de fortes chaleurs pendant une durée plus ou moins longue.

Comment: Mes excuses pour avoir attiré autant d'attention sur cette question, ce qui a valu -2 (pour le moment) à toutes les réponses.

Comment: @ﺪﺪﺪ : Pas de problème, je propose d'ajouter un point à chacun ;)

Comment: @Toto Désolé d'avoir mal choisi mon exemple. J'ai seulement fait un petit exemple pour éviter les termes trop techniques.

En fait, je cherchais ce mot pour décrire l'invariabilité d'une courbe de courant lors de l'application d'un couple de charge à une simulation de moteur à courant continu. :D

Comment: @D.LaRocque: On peut tout à fait dire « l'intensité du courant n'est pas **corrélée** au couple de charge. »

Comment: @Toto En fait, je l'ai formulé comme ceci : "ces courbes n’ont pas été affectées par l’application de la charge"

Answer (score 3):

Pour une tournure mathématique, il est possible d'utiliser "invariant".

> Ces courbes sont invariantes à la canicule.

Mais cela ne "sonne" pas très bien.

> Ces courbes sont décorrélées de la canicule.

Passe mieux, à mon avis.

Answer (score -4):

Le choix initial de mise en relation de termes (courbe/insensible) entraine un ensemble d'impropriétés, ce qui a été ressenti, je crois, justement, par user **Fólkvangr** (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=51913551#51913551) bien que semble-t-il, il n'ait pas pu ou su pointer le problème.

Dans les  sciences physiques et en particulier la technologie des appareils de mesure électronique, l'utilisation de ce terme présuppose le plus souvent un système capable de réactions en fonction d'un stimulus et on dit que le système est plus ou moins sensible au stimulus, cela étant évalué souvent par un seuil, appelé la sensibilité, à partir duquel une réaction est (n'est pas) enregistrée lorsque le seuil est franchi dans une première direction (dans la seconde) ([réf.1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensibilit%C3%A9), [réf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity#Biology_and_medicine)). Il est donc nécessaire lorsque le terme est utilisé dans ces domaines qu'il existe un contexte d'exposition d'un système à un agent modificateur.

- Une courbe n'est pas un système ; le système ici c'est une partie de l'atmosphère pour laquelle la fonction du temps appelée température est considérée. la courbe n'est que la représentation du niveau d'énergie du système dans le temps.  Il ne peut pas exister de sensibilité de la courbe.
- La canicule n'est pas autre chose que le phénomène atmosphérique d'une chaleur de l'air supérieure à un niveau déterminé comme étant celui auquel les humains commencent a ressentir un certain inconfort. Ce n'est pas une entrée dans le système (input) mais c'est quelque chose qui fait partie du système.
- De plus cette chaleur correspond à une température unique. Donc, dans une partie donnée de l'atmosphère soit la canicule existe soit elle n'est pas vérifiable et dans ce dernier cas il ne peut évidemment pas y avoir de température correspondante, ou en d'autres termes il ne peut pas exister de courbe de température correspondant à une canicule. Il n'y a même pas de logique dans l'assertion « La canicule n'affecte pas la région. ». On peut dire « La canicule ne s'étend pas jusqu'à cette région. ». La canicule n'est pas l'énergie solaire, qui a une valeur constante sur le dessus de la couche atmosphérique pour un angle constant des rayons et qui serait donc la même partout pour des régions exposées selon le même angle ; la canicule c'est un état énergétique d'une partie de l'atmosphère affecté par l'énergie solaire, l'effet calorifique de laquelle est modifiée pour une région donnée par une multitude de facteurs (angle par rapport aux rayons, altitude, mouvements d'air, …). Que la canicule n'est qu'un phénomène local est clair d'après la définition suivante du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/canicule).

> B. Par analalogie, cour. Très forte chaleur. Heure, jour, nuit, soir de canicule; ardente canicule.
>
> - La canicule constante de la chambre de chauffe (A. DAUDET, Jack, t. 2, 1876, p. 117) :

L'exemple de l'utilisation du mot « sensible » en rapport avec les procédures de recherche de texte en informatique illustre bien ce concept ; lorsque l'on dit « sensible à la casse » on parle d'un système, le programme de recherche et le texte dans lequel est faite la recherche et à ce système est appliqué un stimulus celui-ci étant  la casse de du texte recherché ; il y a bien une exposition d'un système à un phénomène et ce phénomène est externe au système ; le phénomène est toujours soumis à l'analyse du système qu'il soit un système configuré pour reconnaitre la casse ou non ; il peut avoir un effet  ou ne pas en avoir, c'est à dire que le système peut  être sensible à ce stimulus ou non, mais le stimulus est toujours une entrée (input).

Pour respecter les notions sémantiques acquises je pense donc qu'il vaudrait beaucoup mieux dire ceci.

- En comparant les courbes de température des stations météo de la région, on voit que toutes montrent que les températures ont augmenté durant la canicule sauf celles venant du Col du Bouquetin. Cette région n'est pas sujette à la canicule, ce qui peut être expliqué par le froid de la montagne.

Tout au contraire de rechercher un synonyme plus scientifique, qui n'existe pas, et qui de toute façon ne rendrait pas cette construction plus adéquate, j'y substituerais un terme non scientifique de sorte à préserver une assertion basée sur les courbes, terme qui néanmoins a sa place dans le discours scientifique (comme « montrer » par exemple).

- En comparant les courbes de température des stations météo de la région, on voit que toutes montrent que les températures ont augmenté durant la canicule sauf celles venant du Col du Bouquetin. Ces courbes ne reflètent/indiquent pas du tout un climat de canicule, ce qui peut être expliqué par le froid de la montagne.